# How to create custom share links for Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and Pinterest

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus, social-networking, pinterest

I can't see any solutions out there that allow this specific request without a lot of scripting or meta tags so I'm hoping there's a simple way to do this.

I'm looking for a custom share links for all four social networks. Let me give a concrete example.

If someone clicks on a twitter icon link on my site, they're clicking the following:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status="Welcome to my site and tell all your friends! @sitename #mysiterules http://bit.ly/site">
    <img src="twitter.png">
</a>
```

it will go to Twitter's site and produce the following:
[image]

This allows someone to very quickly promote my site with a custom message that they can change if they like but there's no effort involved outside of clicking the icon link.

This is exactly what I want to do with the other three social networks, with a custom message and links. They can also pull the default logo of my site which twitter can't do.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you use the proper social sharing buttons like we implemented in on our [live campaign page](https://www.cwtvacations.ca/cwt/do/yourfamilyyourvacation), but here is some code I stole from a mockup of the campaign page.

```
<div class="leader-half kids0514-share">Share this on:
    <a href="mailto:?subject=Your%20Family,%20Your%20Vacation&body=Enter%20to%20win%20a%20dream%20family%20vacation.%20http://www.cwtvacations.ca/yourfamilyyourvacation"><img src="images/en/share_mail.jpg" alt="email"></a>
    <a href="https://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.cwtvacations.ca/yourfamilyyourvacation" target="_blank"><img src="images/en/share_fb.jpg" alt="facebook"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.cwtvacations.ca/yourfamilyyourvacation&text=Your%20family,%20your%20vacation.%20Enter%20to%20win%20a%20dream%20family%20vacation.&via=CWTVacationsCA" target="_blank"><img src="images/en/share_tweet.jpg" alt="twitter"></a>
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.cwtvacations.ca/yourfamilyyourvacation&description=Your%20family,%20your%20vacation.%20Enter%20to%20win%20a%20dream%20family%20vacation.&media=https://www.cwtvacations.ca/cwt/images/en/kids2014_share.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/en/share_pin.png" alt="pinterest"></a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.cwtvacations.ca/yourfamilyyourvacation" target="_blank"><img src="images/en/share_plusone.jpg" alt="google plus"></a>
</div>
```

Not all social sharing buttons are created equal, some have more functionality and even old versions you can still use. Pinterest is pretty minimal. [I recommend using the official buttons and full structured meta data](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2013/10/02/tracking-social-media-button-clicks-in-google-analytics/), not doing it the way this snippet from the mockup does.

Answer (score 2):

On Facebook you are not allowed to share a prefilled message according to Platform Policy 2.3: "Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments, and captions."

If you want people to share on Facebook I would suggest using the Share button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Comment: Awww, that's too bad. :( I appreciate the head's up about that.